# How can give the menu permission to perticular user in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, database-permissions

I create some backend menu in joomla administrator like (Manager, admin, Super admin, agent).
First three are inbuilt and agent is custom. I want to give some particular menu permission to agent. so please tell me in database which tables having menu permission to particular user. so i can set the permission. Provide me tables name in Joomla database......

Comment: This is quite a difficult thing to do and is hotly discussed within the Joomla forum and elsewhere. You will be glad to know that there is much better user management and access rights in the soon to be released Joomla 1.6

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution before 1.6 is stable, you can use any number of ACL extensions -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control

JoomlaPraise also has a nice admin template that allows for menu viewing customization called AdminPraise2 that would also do what you need.